# Ext JS and loading data into a form

Tags: extjs

I have build a simple MVC application where I have a form and I need to load data into it.

I'm wondering if I should load this data using a store or directly using the model class. I have already a store for my grid.

So I see this 3 option.

1. Load data using Model class
2. Load data using the existing store (a grid uses this store already)
3. Create a second store and load my data using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If your store uses the same model and the data (record) you edit will defiantly be loaded in that store (for example if you open the form on a double-click of a gridrow) or can be inserted into it I recommend you to go with the store approach.
- If you edit a record (model-instance) that will not necessarily loaded into the grid-store the you should load the data using the model.
- A second store will only be necessary if both points above are true and you also wan't to batch multiple record (model-instance) edits from that form into one request to the server.
- A third option is to bind the form directly to the server, but I recommend you to use the model-approach.

> **Note** that if you need a different proxy for the store and the model
>   simply set one on the model and one on the store. By default the store
>   will inherit the proxy of the model but never the model the proxy of
>   the store